# Monitor progress in service to update controller scope / view (AWS S3 progress)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, aws-sdk

I'm making a call within a factory to AWS S3 to upload to a bucket. I know that I can monitor the progress of the upload with something like:

```
.on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {

                    console.log(progress.loaded + " of " + progress.total + " bytes");
                });
```

However I'm not sure of how to feed this back into the controller scope to allow me to update my html based on the progress. I'm trying to feed the bootstrap progress bar so just need to set aria-valuenow to a value in the controller scope. Is there a best practice for this kind of thing?

Comment: The Angular event system uses [`$rootScope.$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) and [`$scope.$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on). Those function are integrated with the $digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

For information, the solution I used was
Calling

}).on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {

```
                scope.$emit('progressEvent', progress);
                if (progress.loaded == progress.total)
                    toastr.success("Success, " + progrss.total + " bytes uploaded");
            });
```

Callback

```
var progressEvent = $scope.$on('progressEvent', function (event, data) {
    if (data.total!=0)
        $scope.uploadProgress = (data.loaded * 100 )/ data.total;
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', progressEvent);
```